# Productive files from Laravel 8?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

A quick question:
which files or directories from Laravel 8 needs to be transferred to a production system or Muße the entire files and directories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, yes, you have to move all the files including the vendor directory which has all the php dependencies (unless you can run composer install in production, in that case there's no need to upload the vendor directory). If you have local logs and cache in the storage directory, you can omit those.

You will also need to create a new .env file for production.

And, if your are using JavaScript with Laravel Mix, you don't need to upload the node_modules folder, only the compiled js or css files.